How to prove the horizontal and vertical tension of transmission tower?
Assume there are three transmission towers,A ,B and C,and B is connected A and C with two transmission lines,$L_{AB}$ and $L_{BC}$

I have formula of horizontal and vertical tension of transmission tower B, but I have now idea about their proof,can anyone help me how to prove them?
$H_B=[N_1 \times (WW_a \times  \frac{S_1}{2}\times cos^2\frac{\theta_1}{2}+H_1sin\frac{\theta_1}{2})+I_{W_1}]+ [N_2 \times (WW_b \times  \frac{S_2}{2}\times cos^2\frac{\theta_2}{2}+H_1sin\frac{\theta_2}{2})+I_{W_2}]$
$V_B=[N_1(WC_1\times \frac{S_1}{2}\times H_1dt_1)+IV_1]+[N_2(WC_2\times \frac{S_2}{2}\times H_2dt_2)+IV_2]$
$N_1$ & $N_2 $ : the number of the $L_{AB}$ and $L_{BC}$
$WW_a=D_1 \times$  average wind speed $\times (\frac{ch}{15})^\frac{1}{7}$
$WW_b=D_2 \times$  average wind speed $\times (\frac{ch}{15})^\frac{1}{7}$
$D_1$ & $D_2 $ :The diameter of $L_{AB}$ and $L_{BC}$
$ch$ is the height of the $L_{AB}$ and $L_{BC}$ at B tower
$S_1$ & $S_2 $ :The distance of $B$ and $C$
$\theta_1$ :the degree Between A tower and B tower.
$\theta_2$ :the degree Between B tower and C tower
$WC_1$ & $WC_2 $ :The weight of $L_{AB}$ and $L_{BC}$
$H_1$ and $H_2$: The MAX tensino of $L_{AB}$ and $L_{BC}$
$dt_1=\frac{dh_1}{S_1}$,and $dh_1$ is the difference of the height of A and B tower
$dt_2=\frac{dh_2}{S_2}$,and $dh_1$ is the difference of the height of B and C tower
$I_W$ is the wind pressure of insulation
$I_V$ is the weight of insulation
I am not graduated from Department of Physics or structural engineering,so I have no idea about their proof,I just know they are both formulas, not definition, so if you don't know their proof, perhaps you can tell me which definition can derive to these formula?

Tension is force. True proof lies in measuring. For assignments such as these, assume some things that ultimately become the equivalent of the thing you are trying to prove.

your search term is catenary, these things were determined by the Great Minds of Hooke, Huygens, Bernoulli and Leibniz, I'm certain their writings survive.

These are not fundamental physical equations, they are ad hoc approximations. There seems to be an error in the HB one. How is theta defined? WW appears to be assuming a very low value for the wind speed, as drag is usually proportional to v^2. etc.
